# D3: expand a polygon on a map

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I'm working on some different map visualizations on D3. I've got geoJson data and a map that has some .on("mouseover") functions to style it.

Now, I'd like to expand the size of the polygon when I do a mouseover. With rectangles or circles I can just write a function to expand the width or radius. Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Here is an example of my code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#map")
  .append( "svg" )
  .attr( "width", width )
  .attr( "height", height );

var g = svg.append( "g" );

var albersProjection = d3.geo.albers()
  .scale( 190000 )
  .rotate( [71.057,0] )
  .center( [0, 42.313] )
  .translate( [width/2,height/2] );

var geoPath = d3.geo.path()
    .projection( albersProjection );


var mapProperties = g.selectAll( "path" )
  .data(data.features, function(d, i) {return d + i})
  .enter()
  .append( "path" )
  .attr( "fill", "#150000" )
  .attr( "d", geoPath )
  .style("stroke", "#FFFFFF")
  .style("stroke-width", 2)
```

Comment: You could apply a `transform` with a `scale` > 1.

Comment: Please share an example.